# How to get following users posts in Laravel 5.8

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

I have two models in my **Laravel 5.8** project, relationships is shown below in both model classes. How can I get every single post records related with every single user that I follow using just a single sql query ? Can I get it using **Eloquent Query Builder** or I need a **Raw SQL Query** ? Can Someone show me the SQL query to do it ?

Sorry, I didn't know what title to put in the question.

Thanks in advance !

User Class.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail{

   use Notifiable, MessageAccessible, TagsCreator;

   /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $fillable = [
      'name',
      "lastname",
      "country",
      "city",
      "phone_number",
      'e_mail',
      'password',
      "role_id",
      "profile_picture",
      "occupation",
      "biography"
   ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $hidden = [
      'password',
      'remember_token'
   ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $casts = ['email_verified_at' => 'datetime'];

   public function posts(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
   }

   public function followers(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follower_followed', 'followed_id', 'follower_id');
   }

   public function following(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follower_followed', 'follower_id', 'followed_id');
   }
}
```

Post Class.

```
class Post extends Model{

   /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $fillable = [
      'user_id',
      "post_permission_id",
      "title",
      "content",
      "likes",
      "dislikes"
   ];

   public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is this.

Not sure but in some Laravel versions you have to use `select` instead of `pluck` here. This defo works in 5.6

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', User::find($user_id)->followers->pluck('id'))->get();
```

then you might wanna order the posts by follower

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', User::find($user_id)->followers->pluck('id'))->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')->get();
```

Here is the Documentation for [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) Scroll a bit down, there is no direct anchor on whereIn :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. That could work, could you tell me what the sql sentence would be like to achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean? Btw... in Laravel 5.6 it would be `pluck()` not sure in 5.8

Comment: How could I do it with an raw SQL query ?

Comment: You can debug the queries created by Eloquent, have a look at this article https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel but why would you do that in raw sql?

Answer (score 1):

After finding/selecting the user, you can get the related posts with something like this:

```
$user = Auth::user(); // selecting the logged in user
$user->posts;
```

For this to work, you must have `user_id` column in the `posts` table.

And if you want to have all users and their posts, you can do this:

```
$usersWithPosts = User::with('posts')->get();
```

This will return all users (whether they have any post or not) if you just want users that essentially have at least one post do this:

```
$usersWithPosts = User::has('posts')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

$following_data=['0'=>'2','1'=>'3','2'=>'5'];

$follower_post =DB::table('channel_posts')

```
                    ->join('users','channel_posts.user_id','users.id')
                    ->join('category','channel_posts.category_id','category.id')
                    ->join('country','channel_posts.country_id','country.country_id')
                    ->select('channel_posts.*','users.name','category.name','country.name')
                    ->whereIn('channel_posts.user_id',$following_data)
                    ->inRandomOrder()
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get();
                   
                    
       // dd($follower_post);
```